# menu does not showing

Tags: android, menu, indexoutofboundsexception

```
   public void showPopupMenu(View v) {

        ArrayList<String> menuItem = new ArrayList<String>() ;
        PopupMenu popupMenu = new PopupMenu(this,v);
        MenuInflater inflater = popupMenu.getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_size, popupMenu.getMenu());

        for(int i = 0; i < 30; i = i+2){
           // menuItem =
            popupMenu.getMenu().add(menuItem.get(i));
        }
        popupMenu.show();
    }
```

gives error:
**java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0**

Comment: ArrayList<String> menuItem doesn't have any item. that's why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since **menuItem** does not have any item, as you are not adding anything in it, it is giving the **java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0**.

Please try to add some items first.

Answer (score 0):

> According to ur code

```
 public void showPopupMenu(View v) {

   ArrayList<String> menuItem = new ArrayList<String>() ;
    PopupMenu popupMenu = new PopupMenu(this,v);
    MenuInflater inflater = popupMenu.getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_size, popupMenu.getMenu());

    for(int i = 0; i < 30; i = i+2){
       // menuItem =
        popupMenu.getMenu().add(menuItem.get(i));
    }
    popupMenu.show();
}
```

**menuItem** have garbage values check them again that is why it is not working add some data to your lists then it will show you.